# Get all rows user is authorised to see

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I have `Book` and `Page` models.
Users may be allowed to see individual pages from the book or the whole book.
For example, I have the following `pages` table:

```
id | page_number | book_id
1        1          4
2        2          4
3        3          4
```

User `A` has permissions to see only pages 1 and 2, how can I fetch from the database only the pages he has permissions to view (i.e., 1,2)

Also, User `B` has permission to see the whole book (the permission assigned to the book record, not for all pages in the book), so he should get pages 1-3 (and maybe future pages that may be added into the book).

Is it possible to implement this in Laravel? Maybe with `bouncer` or `Laravel-permissions`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to keep this simple: I wouldn't look to a package to implement, I think perhaps just a couple of relationship tables on the **User** where the pages or books are the models that user is authorized to see:

`book_user`, where you have a `user_id` and a `book_id`

And

`page_user` where you have a `page_id` and  `user_id` plus a `book_id` on the **page** model itself so that you can pull the pages for a specific book that the user is authorized to see.

Make your many to many relationships on the **User** along with a pivot for `book_id` on the `pages` relationship, and then pull the appropriate authorization after you have the current user.  For example:

```
// $user set above - might be $user = \Auth::user() or from an id from a form
if(isset($user->books->find($someBookID))
   $book = Book::find($someBookID);

// pages below might be related to a specific book: pages->where('book_id', $something)
elseif(count($user->pages->pluck('page_id'))
    $pages = Page::whereIn('page_number', $user->pages->pluck('page_id')->toArray())
```

And then send these to your view based on a bit more logic within the if-checks above.

This is really just pseudo code, as I don't know much about the rest of your codebase, but hopefully the idea behind this will give you an easy solution to what you've asked.